# What kind of algorithm am I looking for

Tags: algorithm

Hello I am looking for a algorithm for my senior project, but I am not sure what exactly the name of the problem I am trying to solve is thus it makes it somewhat hard to find an algorithm.

Here is the problem. There are multiple documents made by different users which contain notes on a certain topic. The user has his or her own master notes but I also want to take their notes and create an overall master note which contains the sum of all other peoples notes. Given that the master note is the source of truth I want to look other peoples notes and send them recommendations for items that the master note contains but they do not so they can include these difference in their own notes.

I've done some research and have found things life RAFT, eg leader election but I don't know if that solves my problem. I have also looked at recommendation algorithms but I don't know if that solves my problem as well. Maybe a combination of the two is what I need? I am looking for some help here to figure out what exactly the name of my problem is and some algorithms which help me solve it.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Do you have any more information on how you're defining "notes" and "recommendations"?  This seems like it could have an analog in file synchronization protocols or distributed version control systems.

Comment: So the items in the notes would be in points, or in plain text. How can the content of the notes be compared.

Comment: Mark Distributed version control systems sound like a decent track. The definition and the data structure for notes right now are kind of in the air right now. But on the user side it will just be simple text most likely. Recommendations fall into the category of Person A takes the note 'Apples are green' Person B takes the note 'Apples are fuit' The master note would be 'Apples are green \n Apples are fruit'. A recommendation goes to Person A to add 'Apple are fruit' to his notes and Person B gets 'Apples are green' as a recommendation.

Comment: Haris the data structure for what notes are is in the air right now. I wanted to get a decent idea of the algorithm we could use before I set them in stone. But on the user side it will just simple text.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-supported_cooperative_work might be worth a look, or at least a source of search keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a candidate to **Map-Reduce-Merge**, with modification in **merge** part of course.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any favorite articles describing this article? A quick google search comes up with plenty of options just want to see if you have any favorites.

Comment: the best article is the research itself https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps399.28/current/papers/sigmod07-YangDasdanEtAl-map_reduce_merge.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I will look through it.